# Estimate an integral with a logarithmic weight

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. What (minimal) assumptions are needed, in addition to $f \in L^1 \cap L^\infty$, to have
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^{2n}} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{(|x-y|+\epsilon)^{n+1}} dxdy\le C |\log(\epsilon)|
$$
(for some constant $C$ independent of $\epsilon$) to hold?
Does an assumption like
$$\int_{\mathbb R^{2n}} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{n}}\log(|x-y|)^{\alpha} dx dy < \infty
$$
suffice? Do we need more?

Comment: What is the definition of the symbol $\lesssim$?

Comment: @FShrike I've edited the question replacing the symbol with the definition

Comment: If $\epsilon=1$, you suggest that the integral should be zero. Why? You should add a lot more context, because as it stands your formula is without explanation

Comment: @FShrike $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ (small enough)

Comment: $\epsilon$ very close to $0$ causes problems - the bound explodes to the infinity, and $\epsilon$ very close to $1$ also gives you a very negligible bound. Again - why do you suppose this inequality should hold at all? You should flesh out your question

Comment: @FShrike But I'm not concerned with the quality of the bound. I only wonder under which assumptions on $f$ it holds as written.